# NullPointerException while trying to create IBM websphere SIBus

Tags: java, jms, websphere, wsadmin

I'm trying to create Websphere SIBus using the admin console or a script and it fails in both cases. This is how I'm trying to create it using **wsadmin**

```
wsadmin>params = ["-bus", "test", "-busSecurity", "false"]
wsadmin>AdminTask.createSIBus(params)
```

as in the screenshot
[image]

And this is the ffdc logs related to this exception:

```
[10/3/21 16:35:39:008 EET]     FFDC Exception:java.lang.NullPointerException SourceId:com.ibm.websphere.management.async.client.AsyncCommandClient.execute ProbeId:187 Reporter:java.lang.Class@a3c939bd
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.management.configservice.RootObjectDelegator.getTemplate(RootObjectDelegator.java:386)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.configservice.RootObjectDelegator.createConfigObject(RootObjectDelegator.java:324)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.configservice.ConfigObjectDelegator.createConfigData(ConfigObjectDelegator.java:150)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.configservice.ConfigServiceImpl.createConfigDataByTemplate(ConfigServiceImpl.java:1682)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.configservice.ConfigServiceImpl.createConfigData(ConfigServiceImpl.java:1721)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.configservice.ConfigServiceServerProxy$16.run(ConfigServiceServerProxy.java:670)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.configservice.ConfigServiceServerProxy.createConfigData(ConfigServiceServerProxy.java:661)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.sib.SIBAdminCommandHelper.createBus(SIBAdminCommandHelper.java:1189)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.sib.CreateSIBusCommand.beforeStepsExecuted(CreateSIBusCommand.java:188)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.cmdframework.provider.AbstractTaskCommand.executeReal(AbstractTaskCommand.java:835)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.cmdframework.provider.AbstractTaskCommand.execute(AbstractTaskCommand.java:807)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.cmdframework.impl.RemoteCommandMgrImpl.execute(RemoteCommandMgrImpl.java:370)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor37.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1263)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:673)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1257)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1096)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.invoke(SOAPConnector.java:503)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.service(SOAPConnector.java:337)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnection.handleRequest(SOAPConnection.java:65)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(HttpConnection.java:733)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(HttpConnection.java:522)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
CapturedDataElements begin
arg0:null
arg1:null
```

The script is tested on WAS servers versions 8.5.5.15 and 8.5.5.13.

Is there something I can do to fix this issue as it exists in multiple servers?

Comment: found a solution or not yet?